# Añadir metadata a manifest android

Tags: android, xml

Al intentar emular mi proyeco de android me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

Tal y como dice ahí, he tratado de añadir metadata al manifest y poner `'tools:replace="android:value"'` pero me daba error ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Manifest(text):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="xxx.xxx.xxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
           <receiver
               android:name="com.xxxx.xxx.Monitor"
               android:enabled="true"
               android:permission="android.permission.RECIEVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                  <intent-filter>
                      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                  </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity"
                android:configChanges= "orientation|screenSize"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
}
```

Comment: Seguramente es un problema de versiones de librerías, sería necesario ver el gradle para confirmarlo, pero básicamente intenta usar la misma versión para las distintas librerías.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas utilizando `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`y `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` al mismo tiempo (una es 25 y otra es 26)

Para corregirlo, debes de cambiar a `compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1` y posiblemente tendrías que cambiar `compileSdkVersion 26` por la 25 y `buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`por la `25.0.3` y el `targetSdkVersion 26` a 25

o, actualiza todo a la version 26, que seria cambiar `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'`